# Upside down reversion for a Greek letter

Tags: math-mode, rotating, greek, reflection

How do I type in LaTeX a Greek letter, say \Omega reflected along baseline?
I might have included a picture for what I mean but it should be clear anyway.
If not clear: I want to type a Greek letter in a way that if soemone rotates a printed paper by 180 degrees, that one would see an ordinary Greek letter?
I wanted to use $$ but these pages tex.stackexchange.com do not correctly interpret them.

Comment: To clarify: do you want the letter reflected vertically or rotated 180°? If it doesn’t have bilateral symmetry, those are not the same.

Comment: You want the `graphicx` package, either `\rotatebox` or `\scalebox{1}[-1]`. Since that’s undocumented, you could also `\reflectbox` a `\rotatebox`.

Comment: @Davislor I haven't even realized that if it doesn’t have bilateral symmetry, those are not the same. I actually meant a pure upside down rotation.

Comment: @user2925716 Please see also [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is with `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}(\someSymbol)`, from `graphicx`.  It doesn’t rely on any undocumented feature, and it doesn’t need any adjustment with `\raisebox`, although you might still prefer to add one.

There are two different ways to read your question: a 180° rotation and a vertical reflection are two different meanings of “upside down” that are not the same, unless your glyph has bilateral symmetry.  Since a vertical reflection is the horizontal reflection of a 180° rotation, you can get the latter with `\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\someSymbol}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Or your font packages of choice.
\usepackage{textcomp}
% To fit this MWE inside the size limits of an image on TeX.SX:
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
The four symmetries of a rectangle form a group \(\mathbf{V}\) of order 4
 isomorphic to a dihedral group, a Klein group, or the Cartesian product
\( \left( \mathbf{Z}_2 \times \mathbf{Z}_2 \right) \).  It is the smallest
non-cyclic group.

We can illustrate it geometrically as the four transformations possible by
reflecting a glyph in a rectangular box, let’s say \(\zeta\), across the
horizontal axis to get \reflectbox{\(\zeta\)}, the vertical axis to get
\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\(\zeta\)}}, neither to get the original \(\zeta\), or both
to get \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{\(\zeta\)}}.  The latter is the same as rotating
the rectangle by {180\textdegree} to get \rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\(\zeta\)}.
Any composition of these operations is another operation.  For example,
rotating {180\textdegree} and reflecting over the horizontal axis gets
\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\(\zeta\)}}, the same as a reflection
across the vertical axis.
\end{document}
```

[image: graphicx sample]

In a real paper, you’d want to declare the symbol with `\newcommand` rather than insert this code into the running text.  If it’s not an “ordinary” math symbol, you might additionally want to wrap it in a command that changes its math class, such as `\mathop`.

#### PS

You ask which other letters can be “rotated by amssymb,” like `\Omega` and `\mho`.  There are a number of such “turned” letters in [the letterlike symbols block of Unicode,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterlike_Symbols) as well as [other mathematical symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) that resemble rotated Greek letters, such as ∇, ∐, ∀ and ∃.  (In traditional LaTeX, there are no commands `\Alpha` or `\Epsilon`, and the Latin A and E stand in for them.)  Barbara Beeton brings up that V looks like an inverted Λ. You can use any of them with `unicode-math`, either directly, by codepoint, or [with a symbolic name](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) that is usually backward-compatible.  Since you tagged this question for PDFTeX, in that engine, look them up in [“The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List.”](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: Always you answer are detailed and they are written more clear.

Answer (score 11):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics} 

\begin{document}

\[ \Omega\quad\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$ \Omega $}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Added*:

Simpler, the `amssymb` package defines the `\mho` command for the conductance unit: [image]

Comment: Also U+2127. LaTeX 2.09 predefined `\mho`, but not LaTeX2e. Present in many other packages, including: latexsym, amsfonts, amssymb, txfonts, pxfonts, wasysym and unicode-math.

Comment: Yes. I took it from `amssymb` since most people load it.

Comment: @Bernard What are the analogous commands to \mho for say \alpha letter ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Could you explain more, please?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. You have rotated \Omega by \mho command. How do I rotate \alpha? In other words is \Omega the only symbol which can be rotated by amssymb package?

Comment: `amssymb` does not rotate `\Omega` -- `\mho` is a different symbol in the font; it just happens to have the same shape upside down.  The method given in the answer, with `\raisebox` and `\scalebox` should yield an inverted `\alpha`, although it may not be on the baseline and a different raise amount would be needed then.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There’s another method that solves the baseline problem and also avoids using undocumented features of `graphics`. I posted a separate answer.

Comment: @user2925716 Just look through the list of the symbols in your font for ones that happen to look like upside-down letters. So, `\nabla` looks a lot like an upside-down `\Delta`, `\forall` like an upside-down capital Alpha, `\exists` like a capital Epsilon rotated 180 degrees (although those don’t have their own symbols distinct from A and E unless you load another font encoding), etc.

Comment: @Davislor -- `\forall` and `\exists` are always "sans serif", so not necessarily what is wanted.  Note that `V` is not unreasonable as a rotated `\Lambda`, illustrating bllateral *asymmetry*.  Maybe a useful addition to your answer, which is a good one.